# Symfony redirect response error

Tags: php, symfony, redirect

I got this error when trying to redirect to another method

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag::__construct() must
>   be of the type array, integer given, called in
>   /proyect/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.php
>   on line 199

But I'm sending an empty array

```
return new RedirectResponse('persons', array(), UrlGeneratorInterface::RELATIVE_PATH);
```

Any help?

Comment: If you are in a controller then you probably want to use return $this->redirectToRoute('persons');  Otherwise, RedirectResponse::__construct(?string $url, int $status = 302, array $headers = array())

Comment: This is a good answer, but what happend if a need a relative path?

Comment: Then you pass it a relative url.  The class does not care.  And once again, if you are in a controller then use $this->generateUrl() which give you an option of absolute or relative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the `HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse` class ? Your instanciation looks wrong.

```
// Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse

public function __construct($url, $status = 302, $headers = array())
{
    ...
}
```

Your third parameter is an integer, when an array is expected. The `RedirectResponse` constructor calls its parent, the `Response` constructor, and this code is executed:

```
// Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response

public function __construct($content = '', $status = 200, $headers = array())
{
    $this->headers = new ResponseHeaderBag($headers);
    ...
}
```

This is your error, you're using an integer (`UrlGeneratorInterface::RELATIVE_PATH`, equals to 2) when the expected value is an array of response headers.

As answered by @Cerad the correct solution is to use the `redirectToRoute` method, but it'll redirect you to an absolute path:

```
return $this->redirectToRoute('persons', array());
```

Or, if you still want to use the `RedirectResponse` with a relative path:

```
$url = $this->generateUrl('persons', array(), UrlGeneratorInterface::RELATIVE_PATH);

return new RedirectResponse($url);
```